# How to display images of public folder from main.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vite

This is first attempt using `Vite`

I have `images` folder under `public` directory. I am trying to display them in browser.
This is the code I have tried so far.

```
import data from '../../data.json' assert { type: 'JSON' };

if (data.length > 0) {
    data.forEach (item => {
        console.log(item);

        const markup = `<div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <img src="../../public/images/${item.bannerImage}" alt="Image">
                    </div>
                </div>`;
        
        document.querySelector('.row').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
    });
}
```

Can anybody please help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
<img src="../../public/images/${item.bannerImage}" alt="Image">
```

with this:

```
<img src="/images/${item.bannerImage}" alt="Image">
```

See [vite's document](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory) for more info.